# How to add new line separator into data for oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm working on displaying data from oracle.
is there a way to make the following data inside the table:

example :

> '1.somedata, 2.somedata, 3.somedata, 4.somedata, 5.somedata'

to display like:

example:

> '1. somedata
>    2. somedata
>    3. somedata
>    4. somedata
>    5. somedata'

on the interface?

do i add new line separator directly into the data?

or do i separator them into new line when i query it?

or is there any other simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you generating the `1....2....3...4....5`?

Comment: @MT0 it is like "1.somedata, 2.somedata, 3.somedata, 4.somedata, 5.somedata"

Comment: So the table contains a row where a column contains the string '1.somedata, 2.somedata, 3.somedata, 4.somedata, 5.somedata' ?

Comment: Will "somedata" ever contain a comma? If so, none of the current answers will work.

Comment: @hisnameismyname2 the comma doesn't have to be in there, i just added it in so i have a reference point to replace is with line separators or any other things that can separator my stuff

Comment: please check my solution which converts coma separated values into rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Apex is generating a web page, which means the end result is HTML. Apex, however, will also sometimes escape special HTML characters for you, like < and &. Since you're viewing a table, I assume the source of your data is a query and your "somedata" field is a single column. Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE( somedata_column, ',', '<br />' )
  FROM mytable
```

You don't say what version of Apex. In Apex 4.x, the column would need to be set to a Standard Report Column, which would stop Apex from the `<br>` elements. I forget what the column type is in Apex 5.x.

Comment: I tried this, it will only add <br /> into my result but have no effect.
so the result would be like '1. somedata <br /> 2.somedata <br />...'

Comment: For that column of the report, you need to change Escape Special Characters to "No"

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this, here is one if you are selecting from a column:

```
 SELECT REPLACE ('1.somedata, 2.somedata, 3.somedata, 4.somedata, 5.somedata', ',', CHR (13) || CHR (10)) AS split
      FROM DUAL;
1.somedata
 2.somedata
 3.somedata
 4.somedata
 5.somedata
```

Comment: I'm using oracle apex sql command line to run your query, but the result is still "1.somedata 2.somedata 3.somedata 4.somedata 5.somedata"

any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use the listagg function and use '
' as the delimiter.

SELECT LISTAGG(last_name, '
 ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date, last_name) "Emp_list",
       MIN(hire_date) "Earliest"
  FROM employees
  WHERE department_id = 30;

Answer (score 0):

Check below sample query which converts coma separated list data into rows

```
SELECT substr( '1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,',
                               ( case when rownum = 1      then 1
                                      else instr( '1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,', ',', 1, rownum - 1 ) + 1 
                                  end ),

                                instr( substr( '1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,',
                                                                     ( case when rownum = 1    then 1
                                                                            else instr( '1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,', ',', 1, rownum - 1 ) + 1 
                                                                        end )
                                ), ',' ) - 1

            ) as data
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length( '1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,' ) - length ( replace('1.AL,2.AL,3.AL,4.AL,5.AL,6.AL,', ',') )
```

Hope this will help you!